# How to put Pokemon into Pokeball?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I've started playing Pokemon Y on my Nintendo 3DS console. I got stuck when I filled all six available Pokemon slots. Now I would like to put some of Pokemons into Pokeballs in order to get more space for new ones. Unfortunately neither me nor my friend was able to figure out how to do it. Could you, please, help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really understand the question but I think you want to move Pokemon from your party to your PC. In every PokeCenter there is a red PC. Once you boot it up you can access your PC and deposit Pokemon you no longer wish to use.

Also. When your party is full, every Pokemon you'll catch will be deposited into your PC automatically

Comment: Automatic deposit into PC does not work for me. I used a code for a gift Pokemon and when I am trying to receive it, a person who is supposed to give it to me says that I'm full.
Anyway, so what are Pokeballs for? Shouldn't it be used to store multiple Pokemons at the same time in player's inventory?

Comment: Multiple Empty pokeballs can be kept in a players inventory. But when you use a ball to catch a pokemon the Ball+Pokemon will be transferred to your party or PC.

In order to retrieve the pokemon you got from the gift you have to make room in your party. So deposit 1 pokemon in your PC and you can retrieve your Gift pokemon

Comment: You've already caught pokemon in pokeballs. That's how you catch things from the wild. After you've done that, the pokeball and pokemon are basically permanently attached to each other. You only have a maximum of six slots in your party.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your explanations! Now it's clear for me.

Answer (score -2):

I dont know what you are talking about but either you to to the pc in any pokecenter and boot it up it will be able to store your pokemon. If you want to catch a pokemon you buy pokeballs and when you are in a wild pokemon battle tap items select pokeballs click on the pokeball and use it.